# How to call a callback function after click on a button throgh jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that is saving data.
I am trying to execute some line once button work is done.

```
    function executionRequest(action, acting, data) {
        document.getElementById('vpl_ide_save').click();
        if (!data) {
          data = {};
        }
        if (!lastConsole.isConnected()) {
          VPL_Util.requestAction(action, '', data, options.ajaxurl)
            .done(function (response) {
              VPL_Util.webSocketMonitor(
                response,
                action,
                acting,
                executionActions
              );
            })
            .fail(showErrorMessage);
        }
      }
```

Can I call a callback function with

```
document.getElementById('vpl_ide_save').click()
```

so rest of the lines run after that only

Comment: create a function onclick to `vpl_ide_save` for call `executionRequest` no?

Answer (score 0):

I know your question mentions callbacks, but **[promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)** might provide a better way to handle this asynchonous operation.  This snippet has pretty comprehensive comments that should explain how you can implement this.

There are **three main functions** in the snippet. Execution requests are simulated by **`simulateExecutionRequest`**, which is responsible for calling `asyncSave` and then (assuming the save was successful) `doExecutionRequest`.

The magic happens in **`asyncSave`**, which returns a promise. This lets `simulateExecutionRequest` wait until `asyncSave` is done and then call `doExecutionRequest` if the save was successful. Note that `asyncSave` is also the listener on the `Save` button (and since it is called directly by `simulateExecutionRequest`, there's no need to call the button's `.click` method programmatically).

The **`doExecutionRequest`** function is really just a placeholder for whatever you need to do after the save completes. (Right now, it just logs some hard-coded information.)

```js
const
  // Identifies some DOM elements
  input = document.getElementById("myInput"),
  saveBtn = document.getElementById("vpl_ide_save"),
  simulateBtn = document.getElementById("simulateBtn"),
  
  // Simulates saving some data (but is synchronous)
  save = function(){
    const text = input.value;
    if(text){
      console.log(`saved: '${text}'`);
      return text; // So we can know if it succeeded
    }
  }

// Will call `asyncSave` when saveBtn is clicked
saveBtn.addEventListener("click", asyncSave);

// (IRL, execution requests probably happen programatically)
simulateRequestBtn.addEventListener("click", simulateExecutionRequest);

// Defines `asyncSave`, which creates and returns a promise.
// The promise calls `save` asynchronously using setTimeout.
// Because `asyncSave` returns a promise, our other code
//   can be delayed until after `save` has finished.
// (This is called programatically as well as by user interaction)
function asyncSave(event){
  
  const promisedSave = new Promise(
    // Promise constructor takes an executor function
    //   (which takes two functions that are used to provide 
    //   output once the promise is resolved or rejected)
    (resolve, reject) => {

      // Simulates a delay (because I/O is asynchronous)
      setTimeout(saveAndSettlePromise, 1500);

      // Calls `save`, then resolves or rejects promise
      function saveAndSettlePromise(){
        if( save() ){ resolve("saved"); }
        else{
          if(event){ console.log("save what?"); }
          reject("nothing to save");
        }
      }
    }
  );
  return promisedSave;
}

// This is what happens in response to an execution request
function simulateExecutionRequest(){

  // Calls `asyncSave`
  asyncSave().then(

     // If async save resolves, then this anonymous function runs
    (resolvedValue) => {
      // (The resolved value is available here if we want it)

      //Defines some variables
      const
        action_val = "log",
        acting_val = true,
        lastConsoleIsConnected = false;

      // Calls `doExecutionRequest`
      doExecutionRequest(action_val, acting_val);


      // Defines `doExecutionRequest` function (Demo version)
      function doExecutionRequest(action, acting, data = {}){
        // `data = {}` makes `data` an optional parameter

        // Checks connection, and does something with data
        if (!lastConsoleIsConnected){
          console.log(`execution request: 'data' has type '${typeof data}'`);
        }
      }

    }
  ).catch(
    // If `asyncSave` rejects, this runs instead
    (reason)=> console.log("request canceled: " + reason)
  );
}
```

```html
<label>
  Enter something to save: <input id="myInput" value="" />
</label>
<div>
  <button id="vpl_ide_save">Save</button>
</div>
<hr />
<div>
  <button id="simulateRequestBtn">Simulate Request</button>
</div>
```